# How many calls to generator are made?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Suppose I have the following algorithm:

```
procedure(n)
   if n == 1 then break
   R = generaterandom()
   procedure(n/2)
```

Now I understand that the complexity of this algorithm is `log(n)` but does it make `log(n)` calls to the random generator or `log(n)-1` since it is not called for the call when `n==1`.

Sorry if this is obvious, but i've been looking around and its not really stated anywhere what the exact answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are ceil(log(n))calls to the generator**

---

Proof Using induction:

**Hypothesis**:

There are `ceil(log(k))` calls to generator for each `k<n`

**Base**:

log_2(1) = 0  => 0 calls

**Step**:

For arbitrary `n>1` there is one call, and then from hypothesis `ceil(log(n/2)` more calls in the recursive calls.

This gives us total of `ceil(log(n/2))+1 = ceil(log(n/2)) + log(2) = ceil(log(n/2 * 2)) = ceil(log(n))` calls

**QED**

Note: In here, all logs are with base 2.

Comment: But this is strange. For example:

`n=8`, then we make calls to procedure for `n=8,4,2,1`. Generator is called `3` times. `log(8) = 3` so `ceil(log(n)) - 1` is not correct in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Mythio Sorry for brainfart, log_2(1) = 0 (and not 1 as I previously states), move everything one down and the proof holds for log(n). Editted

Comment: Now it makes sense to me. Thanks for giving it in proof form. Really clarified it!

Answer (score -1):

By the [Master's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), your method can be written as T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1), since you are dividing n into half every function call, and this is exactly O(log n). - I realized you are not asking for complexity analysis, but like I mentioned, the idea is the same (i.e. finding the number of calls is equivalent to its complexity)

Comment: But **the OP does not care about big O notation**, he cares about the exact number of calls.

Comment: I realized that after I have posted, but the idea is the same, in another words, finding how many times a recursive function is called is equivalent to the complexity of the recursion.